# How do I raise failure with Scala Try

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark, I can handle exceptions this way:

```
val myRDD = sc.textFile(path)
.map(line => Try {    
   // do something dangerous

   // if(condition)
   //   raise isFailure;

}).filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
```

I'd like the element read by the first map function to raise failure as well, under some conditions. How do I do it?

Comment: Use the `throw` keyword?

Comment: which exception should I throw?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Either`

```scala
myRDD.map(line=> if (condition) Left("some Error") else Right(somevalue))
    .collect { case Right(v) => v }
```

This gives a result of whatever was in the successful mappings. But you probably want to do something with the failures if using the above code (with for example a `partition { }`. If not use the `Option` approach:

Or use a straightforward `Option`:

```scala
myRDD.map(line=> if (condition) None else Some(somevalue))
    .flatten()
```

If you wanted to combine last option with your `Try`, use something like

```scala
myRDD.map(line=> Try{
           /*something dangerous*/ 
           if  (condition) None else Some(somevalue)
         })
   .collect{ case  Success(r) => r } // successful results
   .flatten() // flatten out the Nones
```

IMHO (and many others), refrain from throwing exceptions in scala yourself. I see them as fancy goto-statements that don't jump through code within one dimension, but through different dimensions (i.e, the stack). They are part of the Java platform, so we need to deal with them when we access Java code (plus you might have to throw some if you are building something which will be used by Java developers)

Comment: Using `Either` for explicit exception handling in an anti-pattern in Scala. It should be used for handling two cases and referring to them. Things like `Either[String, Int]` are <usually> indicative of bad application design. I fully agree with the `Option`, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ignoring the actual errors, you can just filter for the condition (given that the condition depends entirely on the line):

```scala
def condition(line: String): Boolean = ???

val myRDD = sc.textFile(path)
  .map(line => Try { // do something dangerous })
  .filter(_.isSuccess)
  .filter(condition)
  .map(_.get)
```